# StompJS javascript client logging like crazy on console

Tags: javascript, websocket, stomp, stomp-websocket, stompjs

I am using the StompJS javascript client along with SockJS
It seems to log every single message and event on the chrome dev console.

How do i prevent StompJS from logging every single event on the console?

Answer (score 3):

ok apparently the answer was just to do this:

```
stompClient.debug = function (){};//do nothing
```